# Out of Sequence numbers for today

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that records transactions sent from our web service. I would like to obtain out of sequence numbers between one number and the last number in the table for that day.

This is a simplified structure:
Table name CARTREQUESTS

```
CR_ID
CR_DATE
CR_ORDER_ID
CR_CUSTOMERID
```

i.e.

```
CR_ID   CR_DATE                 CR_ORDER_ID CR_CUSTOMERID
1540668 9/9/2016 11:59:52 AM    100148466   1087840
1540667 9/9/2016 11:58:49 AM    100148465   1191293
1540687 9/9/2016 12:23:07 PM    100148464   916470
1540647 9/9/2016 11:46:32 AM    100148463   918195
1540629 9/9/2016 11:45:08 AM    100148462   957676
1540628 9/9/2016 11:44:28 AM    100148461   1161585
1540627 9/9/2016 11:43:48 AM    100148460   956791
1540607 9/9/2016 11:40:47 AM    100148459   1161585
1540567 9/9/2016 11:36:07 AM    100148457   1127193
1540548 9/9/2016 11:30:42 AM    100148456   1204204
1540547 9/9/2016 11:29:11 AM    100148455   967946
1540527 9/9/2016 11:27:25 AM    100148454   1209116
1540507 9/9/2016 11:21:54 AM    100148453   1207376
1540488 9/9/2016 11:18:17 AM    100148452   1057770
1540467 9/9/2016 11:02:16 AM    100148450   1216001
1540448 9/9/2016 11:00:51 AM    100148449   1082302
1540447 9/9/2016 11:00:39 AM    100148448   1082298
1540427 9/9/2016 10:58:10 AM    100148447   951007
1540407 9/9/2016 10:56:10 AM    100148446   1209338
1540387 9/9/2016 10:51:08 AM    100148445   1205880
1540367 9/9/2016 10:39:12 AM    100148444   1061172
1540347 9/9/2016 10:34:37 AM    100148443   1215973
```

I need to know how I can enter a CR_ORDERID value of 100148443 and the query return these 2 order#s
100148458, 100148451

There are CR_ORDERID values greater than 100148466 at this time, I just want processed records for SYSDATE-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final working code:

```
select minid+(level-1) missingorders from (
    select max(cr_order_id) maxid, min(cr_order_id) minid
    from CARTREQUESTS
    WHERE cr_date >= sysdate - 1 
     and cr_order_id >= :orderid
)
connect by level <= maxid-minid+1
minus
select cr_order_id from CARTREQUESTS
WHERE cr_date >= sysdate - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The values you referenced do not exist in your list, so I assume you are looking for orders that do not exist for yesterday. If so, try this:

```
start_order := 100148443;
select max(cr_order_id) into end_order from cartrequests where cr_order_id >= start_order and cr_date between trunc(sysdate) - 1 and trunc(sysdate);
for i in start_order..end_order loop
  select count(*) into ocount from cartrequests where cr_order_id = i and cr_date between trunc(sysdate)-1 and trunc(sysdate)
  if ocount = 0 then
    dbms.output.put_line (i);
  end if;
end loop;
```

Comment: Of course they do not exist in the list, that is what I'm expecting the code to return because they are out of sequence. This code results in `invalid SQL statement` error.